# Adding two IEEE floating point numbers in Java

Tags: java, binary, floating-point, addition, ieee-754

I am having a difficult time figuring out how to correctly add two IEEE floating point numbers using Java. I'm not sure how to proceed in actually adding the mantissas together because I don't get how to write a method to add numbers such as:
1.110 + 0.00111 (base 2) for example.

I am using http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BinMath/addFloat.html
as a resource but I just can't seem to put it into code. I need to add these two floating point numbers, put them back into IEEE 32 bit rep, and then put that into Hex.

In other words my project is to take two hexadecimal numbers, convert them into the 32 IEEE representation, add them together, then put that back into hexadecimal.

Below is my IEEE class, and I converted to scientific notation, but no matter what I see that I have to add the two floating point numbers together and I just can't figure out how to do so! Please help with method creation or the actual code for doing such a thing based on the code I have written so far. Thank you!

Just to show, here is what is entered and the output right now for. 
0x41000000 + 0x42000000

```
41000000 // just to make sure I get the write binary
42000000
0 10000010 00000000000000000000000 // IEEE form
1.0 x 2^3 // to scientific notation
1.0 x 2^5
001.0 // adding the amount of zeros depending on how many places i shifted    the exponent. I have yet to move the decimal.
1.0
```

Here is my IEEEDecimal Class:

```java
public class IEEEDecimal{
    private String binaryRep;
    private String sign;
    private String exponent;
    private String mantissa;

    //SCIENTIFIC NOTATION
    private String digitTerm = "";
    private int exVal = 0;
    private String scientificNotation = "";
    //
    private static final String EXPLICIT_ONE = "1";
    private static final int BIASED_EXPONENT = 127;

    public IEEEDecimal(Binary b){
      this.binaryRep = b.getBinary(); 
      //SIGN
      this.sign = Character.toString((binaryRep.charAt(0)));
      //EXPONENT
      this.exponent = binaryRep.substring(1,9);
      //MANTISSA
      this.mantissa = binaryRep.substring(9,32);
    }
    public void toScientific(){

    int baseTenVal = 0;
    //GETTING THE DIGIT TERM
    for(int i = binaryRep.length() - 1; i >= 9; i--){
      if(binaryRep.charAt(i) == '1'){
        digitTerm = "1." + binaryRep.substring(9,i + 1);
        break;
      }
    }
    if(digitTerm.equals("")){
      digitTerm = "1.0"; 
    }
    //GETTING THE EXPONENT
    int indexCounter = 0;
    for(int i = 8; i >= 1; i--){
      if(binaryRep.charAt(i) == '1'){
        baseTenVal += Math.pow(2,indexCounter);
      }
      if(indexCounter < 7){
        indexCounter++;
      }
    }
    this.exVal = baseTenVal - BIASED_EXPONENT;
    //CREATION OF SCIENTIFIC NOTATION STRING
    this.scientificNotation = this.digitTerm + " x " + "2^" + this.exVal;
    }
    public void add(IEEEDecimal y){
    String temporaryMantissa = "";
    int nShift = 0; //amount to be shifted to be normalized
    //FIGURE OUT WHICH HAS THE BIGGER EXPONENT AND NORMALIZE THE SMALLER ONE
    if(y.exVal > this.exVal){
      nShift = (y.exVal - this.exVal);
      y.exVal += nShift;
    }
    else{
      nShift = (this.exVal - y.exVal);
      y.exVal += nShift;
    }
    //SHIFT RADIX POINT OVER BY nShift
    for(int i = 0; i < nShift; i++){
      y.digitTerm = "0" + y.digitTerm;
    } 
    System.out.println(y.digitTerm);
    System.out.println(this.digitTerm);

    //REMOVE THE DECIMAL POINTS

    }
    static String[] lookupTable = {
    "0+0+0=00",
    "0+0+1=01",
    "0+1+0=01", 
    "0+1+1=10",
    "1+0+0=01",
    "1+0+1=10",
    "1+1+0=10",
    "1+1+1=11",
    };
    static String lookup(char b1, char b2, char c) {
    String formula = String.format("%c+%c+%c=", b1, b2, c);
    for (String s : lookupTable) {
      if (s.startsWith(formula)) {
        return s.substring(s.indexOf("=") + 1);
      }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    static String zeroPad(String s, int length) {
    while (s.length() < length) {
      s = "0" + s;
    }
    return s;
    }   
    static String add(String s1, String s2) {
    int length = Math.max(s1.length(), s2.length());
    s1 = zeroPad(s1, length);
    s2 = zeroPad(s2, length);
    String result = "";
    char carry = '0';
    for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      String columnResult = lookup(s1.charAt(i), s2.charAt(i), carry);
      result = columnResult.charAt(1) + result;
      carry = columnResult.charAt(0);
    }
    if (carry == '1') {
      result = carry + result;
    }
    return result;
    }
    public String getSign(){
    return this.sign; 
    }
    public String getExponent(){
    return this.exponent;
    }
    public String getMantissa(){
    return this.mantissa;
    }
    public String getDigitTerm(){
    return this.digitTerm; 
    }
    public int getExVal(){
    return this.exVal; 
    }
    public void printSN(){
    System.out.println(this.scientificNotation);
    }
  }
```